# SharePoint 2013 Excel Web App

Tags: office-web-apps

On a Sharepoint2013 site, there are some excel files uploaded to the list attachments and document library. When user clicks the excel file, it prompts an error:

> This workbook cannot be opened because it is not stored in a trusted
> location. To Create a trusted location, contact your system
> administrator.

I have checked the Trusted Location settings and the default is for the whole ShaprePoint server.

Opening Word docs will download the word document.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this issue is to force Excel documents to be opened in a Client application.

Try deactivating and activating "**Open documents in Client Applications by Default**" site collection feature for a try.

You could also run the following PowerShell to set **SPList.DefaultItemOpen** property value to open list items attachments in client application.

```
$web = get-spweb http://<site>
$list = $web.Lists["list name"]
$list.DefaultItemOpen = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DefaultItemOpen]::PreferClient
$list.update()
```